# Unable to access array inside forEach loop in appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to access the elements of an array inside the callback of a `forEach` block.

The idea is given a list of IDs from `avail_id` (this would finally come from an spreadsheet but for now I've taken some constant values to debug), I have to find all 'products' which can be produced.

Each product (given in `prod_arr`) requires two elements to be produced (given in the corresponding element of `m1m2_arr`)

The 'elements' required to produce any 'product' can be identified by numeric id.

`avail_id` is an array of all elements available.

For example `prod_arr[1]` ie `"Carbon Polymers"` require 'elements' identified by the id `m1m2_arr[1]` ie `16633 and 16636` to produce. Since both are available (as they are both elements of `avail_id`), "Carbon Polymers" can be produced. "Caesarium Cadmide" on the other hand cannot be produced.

Finally the function should return an array of all products that can be produced.

To achieve this, I'm first generating a list of ordered pairs of IDs that are available. Then checking that list against `m1m2_arr`.

In the `forEach` loop on `avail_id_op` I'm expecting `retval` to be populated with the result. However `prod_arr[i]` is returning empty. The `if` statement is being hit as seen by the `match` logs. But for some reason prod_arr is inaccessible.

```js
function getProducible() {
  let avail_id = [16633, 16634, 16635, 16636]

  // Create a list of ordered pairs of ids
  let avail_id_op = []
  avail_id.forEach(function(id1) {
    avail_id.forEach(function(id2) {
      avail_id_op.push([id1,id2])
    })
  })

  // Technically, these arrays will be generated from the cells of the sheet. But the issue can be reproduced even if the arrays are defined directly

  let prod_arr = ["Caesarium Cadmide", "Carbon Polymers", "Ceramic Powder", "Crystallite Alloy", "Dysporite", "Fernite Alloy", "Ferrofluid", "Fluxed Condensates", "Hexite", "Hyperflurite", "Neo Mercurite", "Platinum Technite", "Promethium Mercurite", "Prometium", "Rolled Tungsten Alloy", "Silicon Diborite", "Solerium", "Sulfuric Acid", "Thulium Hafnite", "Titanium Chromide", "Vanadium Hafnite"]
  let m1m2_arr = [[16643.0, 16647.0], [16633.0, 16636.0], [16635.0, 16636.0], [16640.0, 16643.0], [16646.0, 16650.0], [16639.0, 16642.0], [16648.0, 16650.0], [16651.0, 16653.0], [16641.0, 16644.0], [16642.0, 16652.0], [16646.0, 16651.0], [16644.0, 16649.0], [16646.0, 16652.0], [16643.0, 16652.0], [16637.0, 16644.0], [16635.0, 16636.0], [16641.0, 16647.0], [16634.0, 16635.0], [16648.0, 16653.0], [16641.0, 16638.0], [16642.0, 16648.0]]
  Logger.log(m1m2_arr)
  Logger.log(avail_id_op)
  Logger.log(prod_arr)
  let retval = []

  avail_id_op.forEach(function(op) {
    Logger.log ("For op: "+op)
    for (let i=0; i<m1m2_arr.length; i++) {
      if ((m1m2_arr[i][0] == op[0]) && (m1m2_arr[i][1] == op[1])) {
        retval.push(prod_arr[i])
        Logger.log("Match at index: "+i+", prod: ", prod_arr[i])
      }
    }
  })

  return retval
}
```

Running the above code in the Google Apps Script Project editor gave me the following log:

```
9:11:46 PM  Info    [[16643.0, 16647.0], [16633.0, 16636.0], [16635.0, 16636.0], [16640.0, 16643.0], [16646.0, 16650.0], [16639.0, 16642.0], [16648.0, 16650.0], [16651.0, 16653.0], [16641.0, 16644.0], [16642.0, 16652.0], [16646.0, 16651.0], [16644.0, 16649.0], [16646.0, 16652.0], [16643.0, 16652.0], [16637.0, 16644.0], [16635.0, 16636.0], [16641.0, 16647.0], [16634.0, 16635.0], [16648.0, 16653.0], [16641.0, 16638.0], [16642.0, 16648.0]]
9:11:46 PM  Info    [[16633.0, 16633.0], [16633.0, 16634.0], [16633.0, 16635.0], [16633.0, 16636.0], [16634.0, 16633.0], [16634.0, 16634.0], [16634.0, 16635.0], [16634.0, 16636.0], [16635.0, 16633.0], [16635.0, 16634.0], [16635.0, 16635.0], [16635.0, 16636.0], [16636.0, 16633.0], [16636.0, 16634.0], [16636.0, 16635.0], [16636.0, 16636.0]]
9:11:46 PM  Info    [Caesarium Cadmide, Carbon Polymers, Ceramic Powder, Crystallite Alloy, Dysporite, Fernite Alloy, Ferrofluid, Fluxed Condensates, Hexite, Hyperflurite, Neo Mercurite, Platinum Technite, Promethium Mercurite, Prometium, Rolled Tungsten Alloy, Silicon Diborite, Solerium, Sulfuric Acid, Thulium Hafnite, Titanium Chromide, Vanadium Hafnite]
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16633,16633
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16633,16634
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16633,16635
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16633,16636
9:11:46 PM  Info    Match at index: 1, prod: 
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16634,16633
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16634,16634
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16634,16635
9:11:46 PM  Info    Match at index: 17, prod: 
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16634,16636
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16635,16633
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16635,16634
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16635,16635
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16635,16636
9:11:46 PM  Info    Match at index: 2, prod: 
9:11:46 PM  Info    Match at index: 15, prod: 
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16636,16633
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16636,16634
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16636,16635
9:11:46 PM  Info    For op: 16636,16636
```

Comment: @imvain2 Please don't add Stack Snippet to Google Apps Script code, it should only used for executable HTML/CSS/JavaScript code

Comment: @Rubén, ok thanks for the info. I didn't think it was an issue since it is javascript, the only difference was the console.

Comment: console.log and Logger.log while they are similar, they don't always print the same output, considering this, since the OP is providing the logs, Logger.log should not be replaced by console.log.

Comment: As the logs of the Stack Snippet doesn't match the logs provided by the OP, I will revert the edit.

Comment: @TheMaster In this specific case the OP's issue is specific to how `Logger.log` was used.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the comma in Logger.log statements.

```
Logger.log("Match at index: "+i+" prod: ", prod_arr[i])
```

Replace the comma by `+`

```
Logger.log("Match at index: "+i+" prod: " + prod_arr[i])
```

Note: `console.log` and `Logger.log` are similar, but they don't work the exactly same way and don't always print exactly the same output (i.e. Date objects ).

Complete code showing the change

```
function getProducible() {
  let avail_id = [16633, 16634, 16635, 16636]

  // Create a list of ordered pairs of ids
  let avail_id_op = []
  avail_id.forEach(function(id1) {
    avail_id.forEach(function(id2) {
      avail_id_op.push([id1,id2])
    })
  })

  // Technically, these arrays will be generated from the cells of the sheet. But the issue can be reproduced even if the arrays are defined directly

  let prod_arr = ["Caesarium Cadmide", "Carbon Polymers", "Ceramic Powder", "Crystallite Alloy", "Dysporite", "Fernite Alloy", "Ferrofluid, Fluxed Condensates", "Hexite", "Hyperflurite", "Neo Mercurite", "Platinum Technite", "Promethium Mercurite", "Prometium", "Rolled Tungsten Alloy", "Silicon Diborite", "Solerium", "Sulfuric Acid", "Thulium Hafnite", "Titanium Chromide", "Vanadium Hafnite"]
  let m1m2_arr = [[16643.0, 16647.0], [16633.0, 16636.0], [16635.0, 16636.0], [16640.0, 16643.0], [16646.0, 16650.0], [16639.0, 16642.0], [16648.0, 16650.0], [16651.0, 16653.0], [16641.0, 16644.0], [16642.0, 16652.0], [16646.0, 16651.0], [16644.0, 16649.0], [16646.0, 16652.0], [16643.0, 16652.0], [16637.0, 16644.0], [16635.0, 16636.0], [16641.0, 16647.0], [16634.0, 16635.0], [16648.0, 16653.0], [16641.0, 16638.0], [16642.0, 16648.0]]
  Logger.log(m1m2_arr)
  Logger.log(avail_id_op)
  Logger.log(prod_arr)
  let retval = []

  avail_id_op.forEach(function(op) {
    Logger.log ("For op: "+op)
    for (let i=0; i<m1m2_arr.length; i++) {
      if ((m1m2_arr[i][0] == op[0]) && (m1m2_arr[i][1] == op[1])) {
        retval.push(prod_arr[i])
        Logger.log("Match at index: "+i+" prod: " + prod_arr[i])
      }
    }
  })

  return retval
}
```